# VB.NET How to plot ECG real time from serial port?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, plot

I want to read the incomming data from a dsPIC-Device and plot the data to a graph.

What I want is eitherway to:

- read from serial port and plot the data "real time"
- read from serial port, store to text file and read text file to plot
  the graph

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What are your efforts ?

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow isn´t here for asking how something can be done, without even googling.

But... Here is a fairly easy Example for a SerialPort-Handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

How to process the data, e.g. to plot the graph, depends on the data you get.